# Apply CSS to a specific page which contains nasty chars

Tags: css

I have a page called "MyPage" which contains ".MyClass". So if want do hide the content I do:

```
.page-MyPage .myClass {
    display: none;
}
```

This works perfect. Stuff is not shown.

Now let's assume the page is called "MyPage/el". How do I do this? How do I specify the page name in CSS?

The following does not work:

```
.page-MyPage/el .myClass {
    display: none;
}

.page-MyPage\/el .myClass {
    display: none;
}

.page-MyPage\005cel .myClass {
    display: none;
}

.page-MyPage-el .myClass {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: what ?? page name ? this is not how CSS work ...

Comment: I have 20.000 on this website. All are imperatively shipped with `.myClass`. On the page called "MyPage/el" I want to hide the contents of this class not on page "Hello" not one page "World" but just on page "MyPage/el". I know that this is far from being perfect and this is why I asked. Thanks.

Comment: but CSS doesn't consider page name, what you said is not in the CSS world ... unless your are not telling us everything

Comment: So the answer is "No" instead of "what??" Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: the `what ??` is because you said it worked ! so i was surprised how it worked

Comment: by the way you CMS is wordpress ? if it's i can tell what to do instead

Comment: Ah, I am with you. :) No, it is not Wordpress but I guess there are people out there who would like to know this for Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

`.page-MyPage .myClass` are both [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), and are unrelated to the page name in any way. The class selectors must contain valid characters as the class names must contain valid characters, for a full list see [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors). `.page-MyPage/el`, `.page-MyPage\/el`, and `.page-MyPage\005cel` are invalid css class names and as a result you cannot create a css rule targeting them.

You cannot specify a page name as part of a css selector.

If you wanted to have different `.myClass` css rules on different pages, you would need to load different stylesheets on each page `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pagestyle.css">`, or define the `<style>.myClass{}</style>` on a given page.

Comment: `.myClass` is added imperatively to every page by the CMS. I have no means to change this. So I have to figure out how to apply this to an individual page called "MyPage/el" which I currently do not know how to specify. I will read through the links provided. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @kghbln if your working with a CMS, you should be able to add your own html to a given page, in which case just edit the individual page in the CMS, open the html view of the page, and add your own `<style>` block

Comment: Only within within limits. For me the solution was

     .page-MyPage_el .myClass {
         display: none;
    } So this is probably CMS specific.

Comment: @kghbln your solution `.page-MyPage_el .myClass { display: none; }` is equivalent to `.myClass { display: none; }`. Ensure you refresh the pages you are testing on with ctrl+shift+r to avoid loading cached css.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your assistance. Much appreciated!